# How to separate array members I have, being part (Based on number of characters per member / Less than equal to 6)?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, explode

My code contains an array that has 7 elements and each element has a total number of different characters. I want, when the number of characters meets the criteria (<= 6) then create a new array.

The output is expected in the form of a two dimension array,

```
// My Variables, $value & $count
$value=array('as','fix','fine','is','port','none','hi','of');
            for ($i=0; $i <count($value) ; $i++) { 
                $count[]=strlen($value[$i]);
            }
```

Then have output like a,

```
// $value,
Array
(
    [0] => as
    [1] => fix
    [2] => fine
    [3] => is
    [4] => port
    [5] => none
    [6] => hi
    [7] => of
)

// Count the length $value and store in Variable $count,
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
)
```

and then I hope my code can produce output like this:

(Explode element where length <= 6)

```
// If length value in the variable $count,
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
        Total Length(5)
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 2
        Total Length(6)
    [4] => 4
        Total Length(4)
    [5] => 4
        Total Length(4)
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
        Total Length(4)
)
```

This is my question point:

```
// $Values RESULT
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => as
            [1] => fix
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fine
            [1] => is
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => port
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hi
            [1] => of
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples were a bit hard to follow but here's what I've got:

```
<?php
$value=array('as','fix','fine','is','port','none','hi','of');

$final = [];

$accumulator = 0;
$final[0] = [];
$x = 0;
for ($i=0; $i <count($value) ; $i++) { 
    var_dump($accumulator);
    if($accumulator + strlen($value[$i]) > 6) {
        echo "adding ".$value[$i] ." to new\n\n";
        $x++;
        $final[$x] = [];
        array_push($final[$x], $value[$i]);
        $accumulator = strlen($value[$i]);

    }else{
        echo "adding ".$value[$i] . " to existing\n\n";
        array_push($final[$x], $value[$i]);
        $accumulator += strlen($value[$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($final);
```

**Yields**

```
int(0)
adding as to existing

int(2)
adding fix to existing

int(5)
adding fine to new

int(4)
adding is to existing

int(6)
adding port to new

int(4)
adding none to new

int(4)
adding hi to existing

int(6)
adding of to new

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "as"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "fix"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "fine"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "is"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "port"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "none"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "hi"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "of"
  }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20a63b83ad5524c5cd77e111bc15e197bf8bfba2

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you very very much much more,
My Problem Was Solved.